# Pass parameters to report definition using activity. Pega8.6

Tags: pega

I have created a report definition under `-Data` layer and I have set parameter there as a filter.

[image: Report Definition]

Now, I want to call this report under `work` layer and pass the parameter using activity.

[image: Activity]

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well best practice is to call that `Report Definition` through a parametrized `Data Page` if parameters are very few.

Any way you can still pass those parameters to any called `Activity` by using bellow steps.

1. Create one `Property-Set` method before calling report definition and set these parameters.

   Param.pyReportName = "YourReportName"

   ```
   Param.pyReportClass = "YourReportClass"

   Param.pyPageName = "PageName"

   Param.GradeParameter = "ValueOfGradeParameter"
   ```
2. Now call the report calling activity(your 6th step) with `Pass current parameter page` check box checked. By checking this check box you can pass all the parameters to the called `Activity` which you set in the main `Activity`.